# How to ignore session in specific filters

Tags: shiro

We have a few filters that run and we are trying to implement the "hybrid" approach mentioned in the documentation.

Users can login through a web form and in most cases that is ok and using the created session works fine, but for /api/** calls we want to force the use of a tokens and ignore an authenticated user who may of come from a form login.

```
/api/content/** : jwt, api, user
/api/**: noSessionCreation, jwt, api, end
/**: jwt, api, user
```

We would like the /api/** to ignore any authenticated subjects that come from a session (created by a form login).  Right now, if I login through the form page the session carries over to the /api calls and bypasses the need for the token being passed in on the url.

So, once I login from the form these calls will work:

- /api/info
- /api/info?token=123
- /api/content/hello.png <-- This is the only one i want to work based off of the logged in user from the from

Our goal, basing of of the hybrid approach mentioned in the documentation is:

1. /api/** calls must be stateless and always use the token passed to the call.
2. /api/content/** can use a session, from a form login or the standard filter chain jwt and api calls
3. /** can pretty much take in anything - session or token.

Is there a way to recognize and forcibly (in a filter?) ignore authenticated users that come from the session?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you would need to implement your own filter.
the `noSessionCreation` filter will not create a session but does not stop the use of an existing one.

Comment: Yup.  Those filters, jwt and api, after the noSessionCreation are custom filters.  My goal was to keep the usage of those filters consistent with needing the token regardless of being authenticated within a session.  I ended up for now just using Shiro as it is and if the subject has been authenticated pre-my-filters allowing it to pass through.  It works but it can be confusing when you think you are passing in a token yet you were authenticated higher up in the chain and the token is irrelevant.